# Using Ruby with RVM 1.12

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-11.10, gnome-terminal

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and RVM 1.12.4 (stable):

```
doug@doug-OnixN53SM:~$ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   185  100   185    0     0    223      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   968
100  8545  100  8545    0     0   5888      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  5888
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   125  100   125    0     0    210      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   272
100  992k  100  992k    0     0   293k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  488k

Installing RVM to /home/doug/.rvm/
    Adding rvm PATH line to /home/doug/.bashrc /home/doug/.zshrc.
    Adding rvm loading line to /home/doug/.bash_login /home/doug/.zlogin.

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.io/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm/
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues read output of 'rvm requirements' and/or 'rvm notes'

Installation of RVM in /home/doug/.rvm/ is almost complete:

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /home/doug/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

# doug,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne
```

After that, I installed Ruby 1.9.3. And in order to use it, I just do:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a solution.
```

Apparently, this new version of RVM need some configurations. But I don't understand exactly what to do reading this page: https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/.

Do you know what steps I should do? Thanks.

Comment: I just resolved my trouble using the following steps (from http://askubuntu.com/questions/40287/etc-profile-not-being-sourced):

 * start a gnome-terminal;
 * go to Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command;
 * enable "Run Command as a login shell";
 * restart the gnome-terminal.

I also added this `export rvm_cd_complete_flag=1` in my `~/.profile` file.

Everything seems okay, yea~

Answer (score 9):

You need to add this line to your `.zshrc`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

Then reload:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Oops, my bad! Didn't see the .zshrc.

Comment: you should not add this to zshrc, this is potential for bugs and hidden errors, it can bite you sooner or later, check https://rvm.io/support/faq/#shell_login for some details.

Comment: The issue with using .bash_profile is that Ubuntu (and derived distros like Mint) do not have a .bash_profile by default and seem to ignore whatever is in there - when I put this code into .bash_profile as RVM suggests, I get the original "rvm is not a function" issue. It's only when I put it into .bashrc that RVM can be used.

Comment: It works, but every time i open a new shell i have to run 'source ~/.zshrc' again. Why?

Comment: Your system might not be looking at .zshrc, so try putting it into .bashrc instead.

Answer (score 0):

this post help me. You can try this:

> RVM seems to oscillate between being a function and not.  It was a
>   function, and then:
>
> scytale@dur:~$ scytale@dur:~$ rvm system
>
> RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not
>   work. scytale@dur:~$ scytale@dur:~$ type rvm | head -1 rvm is hashed
>   (/home/scytale/.rvm/bin/rvm) scytale@dur:~$ scytale@dur:~$ source
>   /home/scytale/.rvm/scripts/rvm scytale@dur:~$ scytale@dur:~$ type rvm
>   | head -1 rvm is a function scytale@dur:~$ scytale@dur:~$ rvm system
>   scytale@dur:~$
>
> now, all that I can think of is that I was trying things like:
>
> $ script foo.txt ...somethinng with rvm... $ exit
>
> and then it seemed like rvm broke, although it was fine *inside* the
>   script.  I don't see how that could possibly effect any of the bashrc
>   etc files which effect this.  No?